# Update multiple fields in a document with MongooseJS

Tags: mongoose

Let's say I have an ABC schema that looks like this:

```
ABC = mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String
    , x: String
    , y: String
    , z: String
});
```

I want to update fields x and y if the name matched. Is that possible with the MongooseJS 'update' API?

I tried the following and didn't work:

```
ABC = mongoose.createConnection(uri).model('ABC', ABC)
...
ABC.findOne({'name': abc.name}).exec(function(err, found) {
    if(found) {
        ABC.update({'name':abc.name}, {'x':abc.x, 'y':abc.y}).exec();
    }
    ...
});
```

Even if this is possible, is it better to just update the ABC object and use ABC.save(abc) instead? I read in another thread that update is better than save because it's saver. Is that true?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can update multiple fields, you just need to do something like this

```
ABC.update({ name: 'whatever' }, {
    x: 'value1',
    y: 'value2'
},
function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
    } else if (!data){
    } else {
        return res.send(200, data);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answered a question I had. Thanks!